# Can someone point me to documentation for key, value pairs for autostart desktop files

Tags: gnome, kde, desktop-environment, workspaces

I've been searching for documentation for the key,value pairs in the gnome desktop autostart files. I have 4 virtual desktops/workspaces that I switch between and I want to autostart applications in 3 of them. This file only starts the application on in the first workspace, what do I need to add?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry 83x26+425+0
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Terminal 1
Name=Terminal
Comment[en_US]=First Terminal
Comment=First Terminal
```

Where do I find the documentation on the key, value pairs?

If this has been answered, please point me to the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just me provided me with a link that answered my question, but to provide the answer for others, here is how to accomplish most of what I wanted to do:

The Key, Value pairs that I was looking for did not supply the answer, I had to install the auto move windows extension and then configure the applications I wanted to automatically move to different desktops. This method only works on applications installed by get-apt, it does not work on multiple gnome-terminal sessions.

As described at http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/gnome-shell-make-applications-start-on.html, the solution is to install the auto move extension and then use tweek tool to modify some settings. To install the gnome sell auto move extension:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update

For Ubuntu 11:10:

sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-auto-move-windows

For Ubuntu 12:04 or later

sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions

Once the auto move shell extension is install start tweek tool and select

Extensions Screen shot of tweek tool with Extensions selected:

[image]

Then select the settings gear on Auto move windows. This provides a dialog where you can add applications and then specify the desktop you want to use as shown below.

You can also use the dconf editor to select the default desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is described on [freedesktop.org](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/), especially [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html) (the first link on google).

But I don't think it is possible to specify on which workspace your application starts using the desktop file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it did answer part of my question. That site actually seems to be targeted at programmers who are extending the functionality of the desktop file.

Answer (score 0):

Since OP explicitly states that she/he wants Gnome then [here](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) is documentation for desktop launchers in Gnome (this follows standard mentioned by @Jakuje, however to unknown for me degree of compatibility). Also, regarding placing windows at different desktops - check if [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/gnome-shell-make-applications-start-on.html) (extension is quite dated...) or [that](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/18/native-window-placement), is what You are after.